# Entity Framework Core - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using `Microsoft.EnityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 6.0.7 with a database-first approach on an existing database. I scaffolded the entities and context and most entities are queryable except for one.

I'm getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'fldTimeOffRequestID'.
> Invalid column name 'fldCorpCode'.
> Invalid column name 'fldEmpID'.
> Invalid column name 'fldEmployeeComment'.
> Invalid column name 'fldEntryDate'.
> Invalid column name 'fldJobLoc'.
> Invalid column name 'fldManagerComment'.
> Invalid column name 'fldManagersLogonID'.
> Invalid column name 'fldMgrModifiedBy'.
> Invalid column name 'fldMgrModifiedDate'.
> Invalid column name 'fldPJobCode'.
> Invalid column name 'fldPeoplesoftID'.
> Invalid column name 'fldRequestDateEnd'.
> Invalid column name 'fldRequestDateStart'.
> Invalid column name 'fldRestaurantNumber'.
> Invalid column name 'fldSAM'.
> Invalid column name 'fldSeriesID'.
> Invalid column name 'fldStatus'.
> Invalid column name 'fldTempScheduleChange'.
> Invalid column name 'fldUserUpdateDate'.
> Invalid column name 'fldfName'.
> Invalid column name 'fldlName'.
> Invalid column name 'fldEntryDate'.

The entity is as follows:

```
// tbl_TimeOffRequests        
public partial class TimeOffRequest
{
        public int TimeOffRequestID { get; set; } // fldTimeOffRequestID (Primary key)
        public string CorpCode { get; set; } // fldCorpCode (length: 10)
        public int RestaurantNumber { get; set; } // fldRestaurantNumber
        public int EmpID { get; set; } // fldEmpID
        public string SAM { get; set; } // fldSAM (length: 25)
        public System.DateTime RequestDateStart { get; set; } // fldRequestDateStart
        public System.DateTime RequestDateEnd { get; set; } // fldRequestDateEnd
        public byte Status { get; set; } // fldStatus
        public System.DateTime EntryDate { get; set; } // fldEntryDate
        public System.DateTime UserUpdateDate { get; set; } // fldUserUpdateDate
        public string ManagerComment { get; set; } // fldManagerComment (length: 255)
        public string EmployeeComment { get; set; } // fldEmployeeComment (length: 255)
        public string ManagersLogonID { get; set; } // fldManagersLogonID (length: 30)
        public System.DateTime? MgrModifiedDate { get; set; } // fldMgrModifiedDate
        public string MgrModifiedBy { get; set; } // fldMgrModifiedBy (length: 55)
        public string fName { get; set; } // fldfName (length: 30)
        public string lName { get; set; } // fldlName (length: 25)
        public string PJobCode { get; set; } // fldPJobCode (length: 4)
        public byte? JobLoc { get; set; } // fldJobLoc
        public int? PeoplesoftID { get; set; } // fldPeoplesoftID
        public System.Guid? SeriesID { get; set; } // fldSeriesID
        public bool TempScheduleChange { get; set; } = false; // fldTempScheduleChange
}
```

The context entry for this entity is:

```
public partial class LmsContext : DbContext
{
        public LmsContext(DbContextOptions<LmsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<TimeOffRequest> TimeOffRequests { get; set; } = null!;        

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {    
            modelBuilder.Entity<TimeOffRequest>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.TimeOffRequestID);

                entity.ToTable("tbl_TimeOffRequests");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RestaurantNumber, "DRI_IDX_TimeOffRequests_3")
                    .HasFillFactor(80);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RestaurantNumber, e.CorpCode, e.RequestDateStart, e.TimeOffRequestID, e.Status, e.PeoplesoftID }, "DRI_IDX_TimeOffRequests_Multi")
                    .HasFillFactor(80);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RestaurantNumber, e.RequestDateStart, e.RequestDateEnd, e.PeoplesoftID, e.TimeOffRequestID, e.Status }, "DRI_IDX_TimeOffRequests_Multi2");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.PeoplesoftID, "IDX_DRI_tbl_TimeOffRequests_PeoplesoftID")
                    .HasFillFactor(80);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Status, e.RequestDateStart, e.JobLoc, e.RestaurantNumber }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_1")
                    .HasFillFactor(90);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RestaurantNumber, e.EmpID, e.Status }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_2")
                    .HasFillFactor(90);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RestaurantNumber, e.RequestDateStart, e.JobLoc }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_3")
                    .HasFillFactor(90);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CorpCode, e.RestaurantNumber, e.RequestDateStart }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_4")
                    .HasFillFactor(90);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Status, e.RequestDateStart, e.RestaurantNumber, e.JobLoc }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_5")
                    .HasFillFactor(90);

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CorpCode, e.PJobCode }, "IX_tbl_TimeOffRequests_6")
                    .HasFillFactor(80);

                entity.Property(e => e.TimeOffRequestID).HasColumnName("fldTimeOffRequestID");

                entity.Property(e => e.CorpCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldCorpCode");

                entity.Property(e => e.EmpID).HasColumnName("fldEmpID");

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeComment)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldEmployeeComment");

                entity.Property(e => e.EntryDate)
                    .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
                    .HasColumnName("fldEntryDate");

                entity.Property(e => e.JobLoc).HasColumnName("fldJobLoc");

                entity.Property(e => e.ManagerComment)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldManagerComment");

                entity.Property(e => e.ManagersLogonID)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldManagersLogonID");

                entity.Property(e => e.MgrModifiedBy)
                    .HasMaxLength(55)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldMgrModifiedBy");

                entity.Property(e => e.MgrModifiedDate)
                    .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
                    .HasColumnName("fldMgrModifiedDate");

                entity.Property(e => e.PeoplesoftID).HasColumnName("fldPeoplesoftID");

                entity.Property(e => e.PJobCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(4)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldPJobCode");

                entity.Property(e => e.RequestDateEnd)
                    .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
                    .HasColumnName("fldRequestDateEnd");

                entity.Property(e => e.RequestDateStart)
                    .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
                    .HasColumnName("fldRequestDateStart");

                entity.Property(e => e.RestaurantNumber).HasColumnName("fldRestaurantNumber");

                entity.Property(e => e.SAM)
                    .HasMaxLength(25)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldSAM");

                entity.Property(e => e.SeriesID).HasColumnName("fldSeriesID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("fldStatus");

                entity.Property(e => e.TempScheduleChange).HasColumnName("fldTempScheduleChange");

                entity.Property(e => e.UserUpdateDate)
                    .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
                    .HasColumnName("fldUserUpdateDate");

                entity.Property(e => e.fName)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldfName");

                entity.Property(e => e.lName)
                    .HasMaxLength(25)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("fldlName");
            });
            
            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

All the column names match what's in the database. Did something get scaffolded incorrectly?

**EDIT**
Here is the DDL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_TimeOffRequests](
    [fldTimeOffRequestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [fldCorpCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [fldRestaurantNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fldEmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fldSAM] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [fldRequestDateStart] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [fldRequestDateEnd] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [fldStatus] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [fldEntryDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [fldUserUpdateDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [fldManagerComment] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [fldEmployeeComment] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [fldManagersLogonID] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [fldMgrModifiedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [fldMgrModifiedBy] [varchar](55) NULL,
    [fldfName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [fldlName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [fldPJobCode] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [fldJobLoc] [tinyint] NULL,
    [fldPeoplesoftID] [int] NULL,
    [fldSeriesID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [fldTempScheduleChange] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_TimeOffRequests] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [fldTimeOffRequestID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_TimeOffRequests] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_TimeOffRequests_fldTempScheduleChange]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fldTempScheduleChange]
GO
```

Here is the SQL the EntityFrameworkCore is generating:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [t].[fldTimeOffRequestID], [t].[fldCorpCode], [t].[fldEmpID], [t].[fldEmployeeComment], [t].[fldEntryDate], [t].[fldJobLoc], [t].[fldManagerComment], [t].[fldManagersLogonID], [t].[fldMgrModifiedBy], [t].[fldMgrModifiedDate], [t].[fldPJobCode], [t].[fldPeoplesoftID], [t].[fldRequestDateEnd], [t].[fldRequestDateStart], [t].[fldRestaurantNumber], [t].[fldSAM], [t].[fldSeriesID], [t].[fldStatus], [t].[fldTempScheduleChange], [t].[fldUserUpdateDate], [t].[fldfName], [t].[fldlName]
FROM [TimeOffRequest] AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[fldEntryDate] DESC
```

It looks like it's stripping out the "tbl_" prefix from the table name. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Is your connection string pointed to right database?

Comment: Have you turned on any logging to see the sql? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I edited the post to contain the DDL for the table as well as the SQL EF Core is generating. It looks like the generated SQL is missing the "tbl_" prefix that the table has. How do I prevent EF Core from removing that? Is this a bug?

Comment: Certainly the `db.Set<T>()` function only supports one type being mapped to one table. Though owned types complicate this picture slightly. And I believe it is possible to map a single type to a table & a view or function result at the same time. Of course you can trivially define `class TblTimeOffRequest : TimeOffRequest {}` for the other table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is two tables in the database with similar names…

- tbl_TimeOffRequest
- TimeOffRequest

EF Core mapped them to the same Entity: TimeOffRequest. Obviously this is a wacky data structure, so the EF Core team probably didn't account for this scenario.